# Image doesn't show up in iPhone Launch screen

Tags: ios, xcode, launch-screen

I have images that don't show up when I use it in:

- (iPhone) launch-screen

But images show up in:

- (simulator) random views of the storyboard
- (simulator) launch-screen
- (iPhone) random views of the storyboard

It looks like I messed up with my Assests folder(s), moreover I checked and normally in **Copy bundle resources** there is 3 items (launchscreen, main.storyboard, Assets.xcassets)

In my case there is only the Launch-screen one.

In parenthesis there is written (1 of 3)? What does it mean?

When I try to add the missing ones to this list, it doesn't show up (main.storyboard file neither Assets.xcassets)

How can I add this back to the list?

Is this related to my problem with images that doesn't show up in the launch-screen?

Do you have any explanation (or a link?) on how xCode(9) is doing the work behind the compilation-load-bar, related to:

- the Copy bundle resources settings?
- the assets?

[image: Missing items in Copy bundle resources]

Comment: Try to remove the app completely from the device and try again. The launch screen updates on device only when install a clean version :)

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work. Are you sure about this update behaviour, I remember I already did updates on the launch-screen without having to completely remove the app to see changes

Comment: It happened to me too many times, maybe it reproduces only on special cases

Comment: At us such problem was, that in TestFlight and App Store build the image did not change on new. I created a question on so, but I did not get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click + button under "Copy bundle resource" and add both main.storyboard and Assets.xcassets from the pop up.

**EDIT:**
in case the sources are not available in the pop up. search them in finder and drag and drop to project to add them again. (since those might have got deleted with their reference.)

Comment: ***When I try to add the missing ones to this list, it doesn't show up (main.storyboard file neither Assets.xcassets)*** I tried to add it back, but it doesn't propose me those files in the list, I guess it's because of the "1 of 3", he somehow still consider them in the list?

Comment: so it might be the case, you moved out the reference by accident while deleting. Search them in finder, and then try to drag and drop in your project, make sure to check the "copy items if needed" option while adding. the files will start appearing in "Copy bundle resource" area.